# GlobalProtect vpn on ubuntu 18.04 continuously reconnecting

Tags: networking, 18.04, internet, vpn, disconnect

I have this issue when trying to use GlobalProtect vpn software where the connection keeps disconnecting and reconnecting continuously like almost every second.

I generally don't have any wifi connectivity issues so not sure where to look.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.
-U

Comment: bumping this thread to hopefully get an answer soon.

Comment: Just curious, are you using the GUI version or the CLI version? https://docs.paloaltonetworks.com/globalprotect/5-1/globalprotect-app-user-guide/globalprotect-app-for-linux/download-and-install-the-globalprotect-app-for-linux.html#id181NC050F59_id9a8bc8e8-4769-4102-8ff7-286bc86bf4d2